# NHibernate Criteria Collection Contains

Tags: nhibernate

I have a parent/child relationship mapped with a many-to-many set.

```
public class Parent
{
    public ISet<Child> Children { get; set; }
}

public class Child {}

public class ParentMap : ClassMap<Parent>
{
    HasManyToMany(x => x.Children)
        .AsSet();
}
```

How can I write a query to select all of the parents that contain a given child?  I would have guessed that it would be something like this, but this API does not exist:

```
Session.CreateCriteria<Parent>()
   .Add(Expression.Contains("Children", child)
   .List<Parent>();
```

I can't for the life of me find the answer anywhere.  My brain is not fully functioning today and Google has so far failed me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
Session.CreateCriteria<Parent>()
   .CreateCriteria("Children")
   .Add(Expression.Eq("Id", child.Id)
   .List<Parent>();
```

or

```
Session.CreateCriteria<Parent>()
   .CreateCriteria("Children")
   .Add(Expression.In("Id", child.Id)
   .List<Parent>();
```

so you can pass in an array of Ids.

Comment: Ya, I thought of that, but something about comparing IDs in NHibernate seems wrong.  I know it's asthetic, so still would like to know if there is another way.

Comment: Why wrong? The purpose of Id is to uniquely identify your objects in the DB.

Comment: Well that's just it, the purpose of the ID is to tell *NHibernate* how to uniquely identify my entities so that I can just deal with objects.  If Child was a unary relationship from Parent, I would say Expression.Eq("Child", child) and wouldn't say anything about the ID.  I know I'm being nitpicky here, I just figured that something existed in the Criteria API for Contains and could be used just like all other entity comparison is done.

Comment: Yah, good point. Using the Id has always worked fine for me, but I'd probably use the child object instead also.