# How to query over a key-value collection using NHibernate?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, queryover

I have the following scenario, a **Customer** who can have bank accounts in several **Banks**. This relation is described as an IDictionary in the **Customer** class (mapped using the *map* tag):

```
public class Customer
{
    public virtual IDictionary<Bank, string> Banks
    {
        get { return _Banks; }
        set { _Banks = value; }
    }
    private IDictionary<Bank, string> _Banks = new Dictionary<Bank, string>();
}
```

Each key in the IDictionary represents a **Bank** where the **Customer** has an account, and the string value is a simple status not relevant for this question.

What I would like to do is a NHibernate query to retrieve all **Customers** that have an account in a specified **Bank**. I tried this inside the Bank class (hence the *this* keyword is referring to a Bank):

```
IList<Customer> customers = session.QueryOver<Customer>()
                                   .Where(x => x.Banks.Keys.Contains(this))
                                   .List();
```

And even thought the above query compiles without errors when I try to run it I get the following exception:

> System.Exception: Unrecognised method call: System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1[[Finance.Bank, Finance, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]:Boolean Contains(Finance.Bank)

So how can I correctly perform this kind of query? Thanks!

PS: [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1330196/nhibernate-criteria-collection-contains) shows how to do it for an *ISet* collection, and [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2769351/nhibernate-query-against-the-key-field-of-a-dictionary-map) states that what I'm attempting may not be possible using the ICriteria API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more research I realized that the logic contained in the **Contains** method probably can't be easily translated into SQL in a generic way, and that's why I was getting that exception.

For anyone interested, I came up with the following workaround:

```
IList<Guid> customerIds = session.CreateSQLQuery(
            "SELECT Customer_ID FROM Banks WHERE Bank_ID = '" + this.ID + "'")
            .List<Guid>();

Guid[] array = new Guid[customerIds.Count];
customerIds.CopyTo(array, 0);

IList<Customer> customers = session.QueryOver<Customer>()
                .Where(Restrictions.In("ID", array)).List();
```

First it fetches all **Customer_IDs** from the association table for a given **Bank_ID**. Then the resulting list of **Customer_IDs** is used in a second query to retrieve the **Customers** objects.

PS: This solution worked on **SQL Server**, but when I switched to **MySql** I had to slightly change it because they represent the [Guid structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.aspx) in different ways.