# NHibernate query: string contained in either parent or child property

Tags: c#, sql, nhibernate

I'm tearing my hair out on this one...

Suppose we have a list of blogs which have tags assigned to them. The user searches for any term, and the result must include:

1. All blogs whose name contains the term **OR**
2. All blogs where any tags name contains the term
3. Only the tags whose name matches the term

The SQL-query that achieves this:

```sql
declare @query varchar(20) = '%name%';
SELECT *
 FROM Blogs blog
INNER join BlogTags bt on blog.ID = bt.BlogId --join table
INNER join Tags tag on tag.Id = bt.TagId
                   and tag.name like @query -- condition 3
WHERE blog.name like @query -- condition 1
   OR tag.name like @query -- condition 2
```

I've been trying all day to make this work in an NHibernate query, but I'm always stuck on the OR condition since they don't refer to the same object.
Using `Restrictions.Like` doesn't seem to understand that I want a nested property and filtering a nested object is typically done using `CreateCriteria` which is not available inside a `Restrictions.Or`.
I also haven't found a way to incorporate condition 3.

I don't really care if it's done using `Query`, `QueryOver` or `CreateCriteria`. Currently, I just want it to work :)

---

Possibly relevant other SO questions:

- [Filtering children](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1330384/2158015)

  - Answer: `Session.CreateCriteria<Parent>().CreateCriteria("Children").Add(/*...*/)`
- [Restrictions.Or](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8128085/2158015)
- [String.Contains in NHibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11601668/2158015)

  - Answer: `Session.QueryOver<Blog>().WhereRestrictionOn(c => c.Name).IsLike("")`

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the query doesn't make much sense. Condition 3 equals condition 2 and by combining conditions 1 and 2 with `OR` those become `true` if condition 3 is `true`. But if condition 3 is `false` the row won't be returned due to the `inner join`.

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of my comment above the following query should do the trick (the trick being the use of Aliases). I'm assuming that you have a class `Blog` which has a property `List<Tag> Tags`.

```
Blog bAlias = null;
Tag tAlias = null;

var blogs = session.QueryOver<Blog>(() => bAlias)
  .JoinAlias(() => bAlias.Tags, () => tAlias)
  .WhereRestrictionOn(_ => tAlias.Name).IsLike("%name%") // condition 3
  .Where(Restrictions.Disjunction()
     .Add(Restrictions.On<Blog>(_ => bAlias.Name).IsLike("%name%")) // condition 1
     .Add(Restrictions.On<Tag>(_ => tAlias.Name).IsLike("%name%")) // condition 2
  )
  .List<Blog>();
```

However, as in my comment above, condition 3 does not really make much sense here, unless you change the `inner join` to a `left outer join`.